# Finding a dynamically-generated child node (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a navbar / header which displays routes inside popup menus which are in turn dynamically generated based on route permissions received from the API. The problem is, I want to hide a popup menu whenever a click is registered outside of it. Currently I can do this, but I'm doing something of an antipattern to get it done and I'd like to figure out a better way to do it.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleClickOutside);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleClickOutside);
}

handleClickOutside(event) {
  let { focused } = this.state;
  if (event.target.id && event.target.id === 'navbar-link') {
    focused = '';
    this.setState({ focused });
  } else if (focused && !document.getElementById(focused).contains(event.target)) {
      focused = '';
      this.setState({ focused });
    }
  }
```

The problem lies in document.getElementById. As best as I've been able to figure out, the better way to do this is to handle it with refs to the given popup menu and comparing it to the event target to see if one contains the other. However, what I can't figure out is how to set or find the ref to a child being dynamically generated several layers downstream of the parent.

The application is currently using React 16.2, so I don't have access to React.createRef to manually set them and pass it through forwarded refs. Anything pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of popups do you mean? why not just setState to close the popup when you click outside of it instead of targeting a dom element?

Comment: The problem there is with determining whether an outside click is in fact outside of the given element. To do that I need to be able to identify the open popup, and see whether the element currently being click on resides within that popup or not and close it based on that.

It's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious but I don't see how to do that without being able to identify the popup element

Comment: https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside

Comment: This may be handy in your case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by rendering an inner and outer div for the popup component, and then stopping click propagation from the inner to the outer div, while closing the popup on click of the outer div. The outer div should cover the rest of the screen. It's common to add some opacity to darken the rest of the page

```
const style = {
  position: 'fixed',
  zIndex: 1,
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%',
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
}
return (
  <div style={style} onClick={this.props.closePopup}>
      <div onClick={this.innerClick}>
         <Popup/>
      </div>
  </div>
)
```

where innerClick is just

```
innerClick = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation()
}
```